# Regex - Do not capture word if it contains another word

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently fighting with regex to achieve something and can't success by myself ...

Here my string: `path/to/folder/@here`
What I want is something like this: `a:path/a:to/a:folder/@here`

So my regex is the following one : `/([^\/]+)/g`, but the problem is that the result will be (`preg_replace('/([^\/@]+)/', 'a:$0'`): `a:path/a:to/a:folder/a:@here` ...

How can I had skip the replace if the captured group contains `@` ?

I tried this one, without any success :  `/((?!@)[^\/]+)/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?<![^\/])[^\/@][^\/]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tTtvMp/1). *Details*:

- `(?<![^\/])` - a negative lookbehind that requires either start of string or a `/` char to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^\/@]` - a char other than `/` and `@`
- `[^\/]*`  - zero or more chars other than `/`.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Tbv5G):

```php
$text = 'path/to/folder/@here';
echo preg_replace('~(?<![^/])[^/@][^/]*~', 'a:$0', $text);
// => a:path/a:to/a:folder/@here
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to match what you want to avoid, and use a [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) approach.

```
/@[^/@]*(*SKIP)(*F)|[^/]+
```

- `/@` Match literally
- `[^/@]*(*SKIP)(*F)` Optionally match any char except `/` and `@` and then skip this match
- `|` Or
- `[^/]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `/`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZuGTI/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/TGdXJ).

For example

```
$str = 'path/to/folder/@here';
echo preg_replace('#/@[^/@]*(*SKIP)(*F)|[^/]+#', 'a:$0', $str);
```

Output

```
a:path/a:to/a:folder/@here
```